# LINQ - Generate identity for object

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

**Context:**

A User is an Entity and a Group consists of 1 or more Entities. 
A user logs in with his email not his entityID (= userID). When a user needs to be created he fills in a form with the information in the USER table (excl. his userID ofc). To generate the user's ID, I first need to generate his ID in the ABSTRACT_ENTITY table because the groupID's and the userID's have to be unique (read: must never collide)

**Question:**

- How do I let LINQ just generate/create the next identity in the ABSRACT_ENTITY table for ID?

In other cases it's rather easy because you just fill in the other rows and it generates it automatically, but in this case there are no other rows...

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: what is the point of the `abstract_entity` table?

Comment: @JensKloster To add a level of abstraction. Later on we don't need to know if something is a user or a group so we just handle the entityID

Comment: so what do they have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
Abstract_Entity ae = new Abstract_Entity();
Entities.Abstract_Entity.Add(ae);
Entities.SaveChanges();

User u = new User();
u.email = email;
u.userID = ae.ID;
Entities.User.Add(u);
Entities.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

Some sudocode

```
Abstract_Entity entity = new Abstract_Entity();
entity.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

User user = new User();
//fill with user data
user.userID = entity.ID;

MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Abstract_Entitys.Attach(entity);
db.Users.Attach(user);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

The idea here is that all the ID's are of the sql type uniqueidentifier which is the c# type Guid. Guids are for all intents and purposes unique http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

if you dont want to generate the guids in the code you can configure your database context to auto generate values by setting AutoGenerateValues to true and in the database set the DefaultValueOrBinding to (newid())

Comment: This a solution, but not the one I am looking for. Using GUID for this project is way overkill. Anyway thank you for the effort. For now i'll just add a column fill it with useless data to force linq to generate the next identity. It's dirty but I can easly clean it up when I have the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Put the things that User and Group have in common in the table `abstract_entity` 

If you can't think of something, then just add a "Created" field (as a datatime). This will be enought to let EF generate a value for `abstract_entity.Id`.
With EF, identity fields that are automatic set, should be ignored when you create the record.
Which is why it cannot be the only field on a table

Comment: It feels so dirty to just add a column with useless information to force LINQ to generate the ID.
I might just add a deleted flag or something, that could be usefull in the future

Comment: more dirty that to add a *table* with no usefull information ;)? But i know what you mean - we had the same problem a while back

Comment: Found the easy solution

Comment: @David nice! post it as an answer :)